# scrollTop() returns 0 in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want to check if page is scrolled after it has finished loading and I'm using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    alert($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

It works well in Firefox but allways returns `0` in Chrome.  Why is this?

Comment: What is the situation? Are you checking to see if the visitor came to your page with a #hash tag?  Or are you checking to see if the visitor scrolled before the document finished loading? or both?

Comment: i'm runing an animation on elements that just scrolled into view . but if u scroll down the page and hit refresh . the reloaded page is scrolled automatic to the previous scroll point (pre refresh) so i want to know the scroll position of window to determine wich elements on the page have scrolled into view and start the animation

Answer (score 4):

Actually Firefox is the only browser that doesn't return 0 for $(window).scrollTop() on domReady or window.onload. Chrome, Safari and IE all return 0. The only safe way to get correct position of scrollbar on domReady is, as mentioned in another answer above, to set an event handler on window's scroll event as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
    });
});
```

Comment: I really don't understand why people down-voted your answer. This really works. Plus, I observed that Chrome will fire the scroll event twice. First on normal page load and a second time if scrolling to the previous position the user was (eg. after hitting F5 to reload the page).

Answer (score 2):

`$(window).scrollTop()` will return `0` when the window isn't scrollable.

Answer (score 2):

The chrome restores the pre-refresh scroll position once the DOM is loaded. So, getting scrollTop on scroll event instead of ready event will work.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the problem that `scrollTop()` always returned 0 in Chrome, whether I used it on `window`, on `document` or on `'html,body'`. I finally found out that css was the problem:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Actually, I don't know exactly why because you can remove parts of this code and then it works again. Strange but problem solved ;)

Comment: thank you so much! it is indeed strange!
Worked on Safari but not on chrome, after I added this to my css, both works on both browsers!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in a page that has some text and a link in the bottom of the page. Remember to have enough text or blank lines in order to make a scroll of the page until you can see the my button

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        alert($(window).scrollTop()); // first load if you did not scroll = 0
        $("#button").click(function () { alert($(window).scrollTop()); }); 
        // hitting the button that is located on bottom of page 
        // - i had to scroll the page = xxx (68 in may case)
    });
```

It is normal in your case to get 0 because the page is not scrolled, the offset between your position and the top of the page is 0.

I tried in Chrome, FF6, IE9.
I hope i was helpful.

Comment: clicking the #button to get .scrollTop() is not the issue .. if u scroll down the page and hit refresh . the page will loade from the point u scrolled to (pre refresh) .. and thats the position i want to know . and if u do that in FF will output the corect value . in Chrome 14.0 it returns 0 .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but got fixed by adding the document declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```